# How React manages state in Production

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and I am a beginner right now. However, the concept of state management amazes me. I have a question related to that only. So, for example, I have a React app that is running on the localhost. The state management has no conflict because there is no more than one user for that to happen. Now suppose, the app gets hosted on a server and now it can be used by anyone on the internet. Wouldn't there be state conflicts now? As an instance, if I have a state "dark_theme: false" by default. If some user sets it to true, **why will it not change for all the users accessing the app?** I am not using any local storage of the browser. Everything is maintained by React.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because React.js apps run client-side (unless otherwise implemented) and simply don't have any built-in magic to synchronize state changes across the Web with other users. (When you "host a [React] app on a server", you just generally upload the static HTML and bundled JavaScript; there's no server component.)

If you don't use local storage (`localStorage`, `sessionStorage`), state is only in memory, and will be forgotten as soon as you close the tab.

Comment: Thanks, even I was thinking in that direction. I mean, I know it would totally be a dubious thing to do on React's part if states were to change like that. I asked this question because I wanted to know how the state is managed for different users. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> As an instance, if I have a state "dark_theme: false" by default. If some user sets it to true, why will it not change for all the users accessing the app?

No. Treat the state as a local "backend" for your app; it resides in the browser for every user just like the rest of the front end part of the app does. It will be different for each and every user.